# Trying to execute sql script using sqlplus from powershell commandline

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to execute a sql script from powershell using the following command:

```
sqlplus username/password@tnsnamesalias 'path to my sql file.sql'
```

If I run the command without the script path, I can connect to the database and execute commands. If I include the script path (which includes spaces) then I just get the sqlplus help text and no changes are made to the database. My sql script is finished with END; and /

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to add the `@` sign before the path:

```
sqlplus username/password@tnsnamesalias @'path to my sql file.sql'
```

Comment: So, I tried that and I get the following error: No characters are allowed after a here-string header but before the end of the line.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedCharactersAfterHereStringHeader

Comment: I needed to escape it with ` thats got it, thank you! So sqlplus username/password@tnsnamesalias `@'path to my sql file.sql'

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten "@" symbol and the apostrophes are wrong here.

This works for me for executing a "test script.sql" file

```
sqlplus .... "@test script.sql"
```